# Click - delay before navigating

Tags: jquery

is there any easy way to create a code: if URL changes or clicked on a link show div (like loading gif 3-sec) then show the page? Kinda like blank white page with loading gif spin 3 sec then show the page?

Thanks!

Comment: huh?  The answer to what I THINK your asking is yes, but have you tried anything yet?  jQuery makes it quite easy to catch a click even on an element.

Comment: @Jared it does not however make it easy to detect manual url change by user (type in address bar)

Comment: Something like in this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytKc0QsVRY4).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Given a `<a class="waitBeforeNavigate" href="somewhere.html">Go somewhere</a>`

```js
function waitBeforeNavigate(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();                    // prevent default anchor behavior
  const goTo = this.getAttribute("href"); // store anchor href

  // do something while timeOut ticks ... 

  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = goTo;
  }, 3000);                               // time in ms
}); 

document.querySelectorAll(".waitBeforeNavigate")
  .forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", waitBeforeNavigate));
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('.waitBeforeNavigate').on("click", function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();                // prevent default anchor behavior
  const goTo = $(this).attr("href");  // store anchor href
       
  // do something while timeOut ticks ... 
       
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = goTo;
  }, 3000);                           // time in ms
});
```

Comment: awesome, this helped me.

Comment: Didn't worked for me. I'm using jquery-1.11.2.min. I don't know why :(

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I found the problem. Ripple.js is blocking my code.