# Only want to page to redirect to desired link after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any possible way for me to have a link and create a code in JavaScript or jQuery that allowes the page to redirect to that desired link after 2 seconds of clicking on the link?

Any demos or jsFiddles would be great to help explain! Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `setTimeout(function(){ /*code*/ },2000);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click on link - delay before navigating to a different location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510478/click-on-link-delay-before-navigating-to-a-different-location)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkxeN/
It goes to the link after x seconds, if the link has the class `delay2s`

```
$('.delay2s').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent browser from following link
    var delay = 2; //seconds
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    setTimeout(function(){window.location.href=link;},delay*1000);
});
```

It doesn't work in the fiddle, because the code is run within an iframe, but I still made it for code reference.