# Fade in/out transition between pages

Tags: jquery

I've written the following to create a fade in/out transition between pages. On my local setup, the page loads in smoothly, but there's no exit animation whatsoever on `beforeunload`, which is obviously pretty jarring.

I've created a quick demo of what I'm currently using on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6r605auw/

Is this even the best way to handle this? If you've any suggestions as to why the `beforeunload` animation seems to be failing, or if you've got a better way, then I'd love to hear them.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
  $('body').css('display, none');
  $('body').fadeIn(1000);
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  $('body').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [**History API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) with pushState and popState - in order to move from page to page seamlessly. What you're doing is bad and the mistake you're making will be more visible as more elements you put in your page.
At the time JS kicks in (and DOM is ready etc) **it's already too late** to do `hide()` or `.css({display: "none"})` because the page was building and visible. You'll end up having an ugly flashy unstable-looking website/application :(
The "other" solution is to **hide initially using CSS**... but search engines will penalize you for that.

#### Use an overlay

A ***better*** way is to have a **fixed full-size CSS visible overlay element** -

```
<div id="loaderOverlay"></div>
```

that overlays your entire page content - and JS-(+CSS3) **fadeOut** that element instead (by adding a CSS class like)

```
#loaderOverlay{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    background: #fff;
    transition: 2s;       /* transition timing */
}
#loaderOverlay.hide{      /* JS-add this class on DOM ready or window load */
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Triggering the "fadeOut" in jQuery look like:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
   // The overlay is initially visible, we need to hide it!
   $("#loaderOverlay").addClass("hide"); // CSS3 will animate it nicely
});
```

Now, the **fadeIn** problem...

the [`**beforeunload**` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) will kick in at the moment when the page resources are just about to be unloaded.
The unloading can last a **couple of ms** (+ waiting for HTTP requests...), clearly not enough time for an animation of `2s` to take place - and the only way I see fit is to target all your links on the page, get the `href` attribute, prevent the browser to navigate - and navigate only on `transitionend` (not well supported) or after a `2100ms` [**timeout** period](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11510698/383904):

```
// When we click on some link we want our overlay to show up!
// Additionally instead of `"a"` you could make sure it's not an external link,
// a #hash anchor etc...

$(document).on("click", "a", function(evt) {

  evt.preventDefault(); // Don't navigate!

  var href = $(this).attr("href"); // grab the href

  // Animate-In our overlay
  $("#loaderOverlay").removeClass("hide");

  // wait for CSS3 to animate-in the overlay and than navigate to our next page

  setTimeout(function() {
     window.location = href; // Navigate finally
  }, 2100);

});
```

as you can see the above works for links, but clearly the browser's **Back button** is not a link in your page, and for that... recurse to the beginning of my answer.