# Onclick="reload_interval();" is don't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code `Onclick="reload_interval(50);return false;"` suddenly stopped working, I think problem is with this js code, when I delete this js code all links can use normal :

```
<script>
        function reload_interval(time) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, time);
        }
    </script>
```

Can anybody help fix it?
Here is my all code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>WEST</title>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Header Section -->
    <header class="header" id="header">
        <section class="wrapper container">
            <a href="#"> <img class="logo"
                    src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/376682_f9d48f510b524878a49d5b147a541ae8~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_328,h_85,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/ai_page-0001.jpg"
                    width="200px" height="55px" />
            </a>
            <div class="burger" id="burger">
                <span class="burger-line"></span>
                <span class="burger-line"></span>
                <span class="burger-line"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="overlay"></span>
            <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
                <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link"
                            onclick="reload_interval(50); return true;">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a
                            href="#"
                            class="menu-link" onclick="reload_interval(50); return true;">News</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a
                            href="#"
                            class="menu-link" onclick="reload_interval(50); return true;">About West</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-dropdown">
                        <a class="menu-link" data-toggle="submenu">The Hotel<i class="bx bx-chevron-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li class="submenu-item"><a
                                    href="#"
                                    class="submenu-link" onclick="reload_interval(50); return true;">Guest Notice</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="submenu-item"><a
                                    href="#"
                                    class="submenu-link">Traffic</a></li>
                            <li class="submenu-item"><a
                                    href="#"
                                    class="submenu-link">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="submenu-item"><a
                                    href="#"
                                    class="submenu-link">Brunch</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a
                            href="#"
                            class="menu-link">Rooms</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a
                            href="#"
                            class="menu-link">Contact</a></li>
                    </li>
                    <!--ICONS SECTION-->
                    <!--BOOKING-->
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <a
                            href="https://booking.owlting.com/%E5%9F%94%E9%87%8C%E8%A5%BF%E7%AB%99%E5%95%86%E6%97%85?start=2022-08-07&end=2022-08-08&lang=en&adult=1&child=0&infant=0">
                            <img class="booking"
                                src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/376682_1c2480f9e55846d88ccfbf262967a419~mv2.png/v1/crop/x_4,y_86,w_864,h_159/fill/w_300,h_55,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/Slide11_PNG.png"
                                width="250px" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <!--ICONS-->
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PLWH8/">
                            <img class="facebook"
                                src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/376682_379bf8b061524e348055feaba91e7bc6~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_39,h_39,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/facebook.png"
                                width="35px" style="margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 5px;" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <img class="line"
                            src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/376682_a3f7cd22abd74ceba06d94951bebf099~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_39,h_39,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/line%20(1).png"
                            width="35px" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <a class="chinese"
                            href="file:///C:/Users/14urm/OneDrive/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB/DOCS/web/WEBCH.html">
                            <img class="ZH"
                                src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/376682_23eaf152098f481f9b7d8d6d02506b6c~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_93,h_56,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/ChinesePresentation1.png"
                                width="50px" style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 6px;" /></a>
                    </li>
            </nav>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
    <!--Script JS-->
    <script>
        function reload_interval(time) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, time);
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        const navbarMenu = document.getElementById('navbar');
        const burgerMenu = document.getElementById('burger');
        const overlayMenu = document.querySelector('.overlay');
        // Toggle Menu and Overlay Function
        const toggleMenu = () => { navbarMenu.classList.toggle('active'); overlayMenu.classList.toggle('active'); };
        burgerMenu.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu); overlayMenu.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
        // Collapsible SubMenu Function
        const collapseSubMenu = () => { navbarMenu.querySelector('.menu-dropdown.active .submenu').removeAttribute('style'); navbarMenu.querySelector('.menu-dropdown.active').classList.remove('active'); }; navbarMenu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (e.target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && window.innerWidth <= 992) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const menuDropdown = e.target.parentElement;
                // If menu-dropdown is Expanded, then Collapse It
                if (menuDropdown.classList.contains('active')) { collapseSubMenu(); } else {
                    // Collapse the Existing Expanded menu-dropdown
                    if (navbarMenu.querySelector('.menu-dropdown.active')) { collapseSubMenu(); }
                    // Expanded the New menu-dropdown
                    menuDropdown.classList.add('active');
                    const subMenu = menuDropdown.querySelector('.submenu'); subMenu.style.maxHeight = subMenu.scrollHeight + 'px';
                }
            }
        });
        // Fixed Resize Window Function
        const resizeWindow = () => {
            if (window.innerWidth > 992) {
                // If navbarMenu is Open, then Close It
                if (navbarMenu.classList.contains('active')) { toggleMenu(); }
                // If menu-dropdown is Expanded, then Collapse It
                if (navbarMenu.querySelector('.menu-dropdown.active')) { collapseSubMenu(); }
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow);</script>

    <style>
        :root {
            --color-white-100: hsl(206, 0%, 100%);
            --color-white-200: hsl(206, 5%, 90%);
            --color-white-300: hsl(206, 5%, 80%);
            --color-white-400: hsl(206, 5%, 65%);
            --color-white-500: hsl(206, 5%, 50%);
            --color-black-100: hsl(213, 23%, 8%);
            --color-black-200: hsl(214, 21%, 6%);
            --color-black-300: hsl(210, 21%, 6%);
            --color-black-400: hsl(216, 22%, 4%);
            --color-black-500: hsl(220, 18%, 3%);
            --color-pink-100: hsl(326, 85%, 90%);
            --color-pink-200: hsl(327, 87%, 80%);
            --color-pink-300: hsl(288, 53%, 66%);
            --color-pink-400: hsl(294, 59%, 48%);
            --color-pink-500: hsl(290, 71%, 39%);
            --shadow-small: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
            --shadow-medium: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
            --shadow-large: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        }

        * *,
        *::before,
        *::after {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            list-style: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }

        /*body {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 1rem;font-weight: 400;line-height: 1.5;height: -webkit-fill-available;color: var(--color-black-500);background-color: var(--color-white-100);}*/
        .container {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-right: 1.55rem;
        }

        .header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            z-index: 100;
            margin: 0 auto;
            -webkit-box-shadow: var(--shadow-medium);
            box-shadow: var(--shadow-medium);
            background-color: var(--color-white-100);
        }

        .wrapper {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-box-pack: justify;
            -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
            -webkit-column-gap: 1rem;
            -moz-column-gap: 1rem;
            column-gap: 1rem;
            row-gap: 2rem;
            width: 100%;
            height: 4rem;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
            .navbar {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: -100%;
                width: 80%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 10;
                opacity: 0;
                overflow-y: auto;
                visibility: hidden;
                -webkit-box-shadow: var(--shadow-medium);
                box-shadow: var(--shadow-medium);
                background-color: var(--color-white-100);
                -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
                transition: all 0.5s ease;
            }

            .navbar.active {
                left: 0rem;
                opacity: 1;
                visibility: visible;
            }
        }

        .menu-item {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 1.5rem;
        }

        .menu-link {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-column-gap: 0.25rem;
            -moz-column-gap: 0.25rem;
            column-gap: 0.25rem;
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: 500;
            line-height: inherit;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            color: var(--color-black-500);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .menu-link:hover {
            outline: none;
            color: var(--color-pink-500);
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 993px) {
            .menu-dropdown:hover>.submenu {
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
                visibility: visible;
                -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                transform: translateY(0);
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
            .menu {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                padding: 1rem 0;
            }

            .menu-item {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .menu-link {
                -webkit-box-pack: justify;
                -ms-flex-pack: justify;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
            }
        }

        .submenu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 2rem;
            left: -1.5rem;
            width: 12rem;
            height: auto;
            padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(1rem);
            transform: translateY(1rem);
            border-top: 3px solid var(--color-pink-400);
            -webkit-box-shadow: var(--shadow-medium);
            box-shadow: var(--shadow-medium);
            background-color: var(--color-white-100);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .submenu-item {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }

        .submenu-link {
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: 500;
            line-height: inherit;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            color: var(--color-black-500);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
            transition: all 0.35s ease;
        }

        .submenu-link:hover {
            outline: none;
            color: var(--color-pink-500);
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

            /*position:relative*/
            /*top:-0.5rem*/
            /*left:2.5rem*/
            .submenu {
                position: sticky;
                top: -0.5rem;
                left: 2.5rem;
                /*width: 100%;*/
                max-height: 0;
                padding: 0px;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                opacity: 1;
                overflow: hidden;
                visibility: visible;
                -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
                transform: translateY(0px);
                -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
                background: transparent;
            }
        }

        .burger {
            position: relative;
            display: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            width: 1.75rem;
            height: 1rem;
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            background: transparent;
        }

        .burger-line {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2px;
            opacity: 1;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            background: var(--color-black-500);
        }

        .burger-line:nth-child(1) {
            top: 0px;
        }

        .burger-line:nth-child(2) {
            top: 0.5rem;
        }

        .burger-line:nth-child(3) {
            top: 1rem;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
            .burger {
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
                visibility: visible;
            }
        }

        .overlay {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 9;
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
            .overlay.active {
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
                visibility: visible;
            }
        }

        /*BOOKING*/
        .booking {
            margin-right: 15px;
            margin-left: 15px;
            padding-top: 25px;
        }

        /*HEADER*/
        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 45px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
        }

        /*ICONS*/
        .facebook {
            align-items: center;
            padding-top: 25px;
            margin-top: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? a delay in opening the link?

Comment: I have to use this code in Wix , without this delay some pages can't open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click - delay before navigating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510478/click-delay-before-navigating)

Comment: This code is don't working too 

Comment: First of all, I'd recommend you use unobtrusive JavaScript (i. e. ditch the onclick="" attributes in favor of an addEventListener() that attaches your function to the objects that you want to use as a reload trigger. Second, it's difficult to tell what reload_interval() is attempting to achieve (I'm reading it as if it is going to reload the current page - that is what the ```location``` object is referencing - however, if you are loading a new page that is going to kill the timeout). However, going by your description, do I take it that that isn't what you have intended?